# Laravel 3 routing issue

Tags: php, laravel

I came from Codeigniter. In CI I had this:

```
$route['([a-z]+)tab'] = "$1/tab";
```

When I go to index.php/sometab/ I'll get some/tab/ action executed. But it doesn't redirect, instead I just tell CI that when I type this address I want to use another address instead, though there is no redirect.

Basically I want to achieve next goal: when I go to /someTab/ I want to execute some@tab action.

I only found Redirect::to_action in laravel, but I dont want the URL to be changed. I tried something like:

```
Route::any('([a-z]+)tab', function($controllerName) {
    return Redirect::to_action("{$controllerName}/tab"); // here I want to tell to use $controllerName@tab action
});
```

How can I get this?

Comment: `Redirect::to_route()` is your answer. It goes from a route to a route.

Comment: I didn't manage to get it work, though, It works with Route::forward method. Like return Route::forward('get', "{$tabname}/tab"); this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Routing.Controller.html

There are some interesting methods here to. Route::cal, Route::forward, Route::execute...

Comment: there is no Route::execute or cal, but Route::forward did the thing